# Appropriate resolution of images for image classification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digital-image-processing, image-classification

I am attempting to perform image classification on some maps that I have in PNG format.  This classification is failing due to there being too many many pixels in the training samples (I appear to be having the same problem as this user: [Failed to create signature file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90937/failed-to-create-signature-file)).

As you can see in the picture, a relatively small training area contains a huge number of pixels as shown in the count column.  The PNG image that I imported to GIS is ~4000 x ~4000 pixels.  The number of pixels in this sample is larger than the number of pixels in the entire .png image!

Is there a setting I need to change to get ArcGIS to recognize the resolution of the image for the sake of classification?

[image: This small training sample contains a huge number of pixels.]

Comment: Typically image classification is accomplished using spatial data (e.g. geotiff, .img, etc) rather than non spatial raster data such as PNG.  Is there any way you can run the classification using a geotiff?

Comment: Consider changing raster cell size in environmrnt settings, make it equal to one in the image